# Is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ a union of countable family of closed sets?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, irrational-numbers

Can we represent set of irrational numbers as union of countable family of closed sets?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Where did you encounter the question? Please edit your post in include this sort of information; bare problem statements are discouraged on this site.

Comment: Closed in what space?

Comment: closed in $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is NO.

If $\mathbb R\!\smallsetminus\!\mathbb Q=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}F_n$, where $F_n$, $n\in\mathbb N$, are closed, then 
$$
\mathbb Q=\mathbb R\smallsetminus\!\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}F_n
=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} (\mathbb R\!\smallsetminus\! F_n)=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} U_n
$$
where $U_n=\mathbb R\!\smallsetminus\! F_n$ open. Clearly, each of these $U_n$'s is also dense, as their intersection is dense.

If we now write $\mathbb Q$ as $\mathbb Q=\{q_n\}_{n\in\mathbb Q}$, as set  $V_n =U_n\!\smallsetminus\!\{q_n\}$, then these $V_n$'s are also open and dense and $$
\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}V_n=\varnothing,
$$ which contradicts [Baire's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem).

Answer (score 7):

No, this is not possible, for if it was, ${\mathbb R}$ would be the union of countably many nowhere dense closed subsets, contradicting Baire's category theorem.

Comment: Can you eleborate a bit more please, Because $R\setminus Q$ is given as countable closed nowhere dense sets, what is the new subset you make union to get $R$?